# Data validation message appears even when textbox has data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation

So I populated my ABCViewModel with data. Every single field of it had data.

One of its field is called Name. Name is required by using data annotations. [Required]

I passed ABCViewModel to my view, with the name field containing a string.

This view is actually used to edit ABCViewModel contents.

The html page appears, with the nametextbox containing the name. But the data validation message appears below the textbox.
[Name field is required]

When I use my mouse to click on the textbox to grant it focus, the validation message disappears.

Any one had this issue before?

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(ABCDetailsViewModel abcDetailsViewModel)
{
      ABCViewModel abc = new ABCViewModel(abcDetailsViewModel);

      return View(abc);
}



@model ABCViewModel

@using(Html.BeginForm("ABCUpdate", "Details", FormMethod.Post, new{name="form", id="form", @class="form-horizontal"}))
{
     @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

      @Html.LabelFor(model=>model=>Name, new{@class="control-label col-sm-2"})
     @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, "", new{@style="width:100%;"})
     @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => Model.Name, "", new{@class = "alert-danger"})
.
.
.
}
```

Comment: You need to show the relevant code. Best guess is your GET method has a parameter for `Name` and not query string/route value was provided

Comment: You need to show your GET method and the `ABCDetailsViewModel` and `ABCViewModel` Do they both contain a property named `Name`

Comment: Yes they both contain a property called name

Answer (score 1):

Check whether you pass an object empty object with null values in your return `View()` method - recheck that you didn't set any default value for Name prop

If nothing works please post your `cshtml` and the controller code 
In your `Html.EditFor()` method check that you are not binding any values - Thanks

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: I think that will be the basic validation you need to do when you write your code